# Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've just installed PHP 7.1 and now I am seeing this error :

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /postfixadmin/variables.inc.php on line 31
```

Line #31 :

```
$fDomains[0] = "";
```

How does on clear $fDomains[0] now in PHP 7.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you want to unset a string at the first element. just use `substr($fDomains, 1);`

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot unset string offsets in /postfixadmin/variables.inc.php:31

Comment: var_dump($fDomains);

Comment: may be your $fDomains is not an array, but a string

Comment: in variables.php, there are 2 lines that reference this variable ($fDomains = "";) and ($fDomains[0] = "";) - I'm not sure of the reasoning for it though.

Comment: `substr` has a terrible performance when you need to perform heavy operations

Answer (score 4):

My reason for this message  'PHP Warning:  Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset' is:
My `$fDomains` variable was initiated as a string, not as an array.

Comment: Not sure why you add your reasoning since this question was solved ages ago.

Comment: My reason is that the googled reply for me was not a solution,as I myself wanted indeed to use the indexed variable as an array not as a string (usual case), so I did not suspect just because of the chosen answer having two votes being versatile/entirely  correct (if at all - happens sometimes) - if somebody like me comes after me and won't find answer here - I had to xdebug it, test on phptester, and came to solution by chance - trial and error, and common sense, as strangely also similar questions were not replied yet.Later I saw comment from Kris Roofe too but it was not posted as an answer

Comment: yes, i need to initiate my variable as array, not as empty string to avoid this warning

Answer (score 2):

Either `($fDomains = "";)` or `($fDomains[0] = "";)` is wrong, but without seeing the rest of the code, it's impossible to say *which* is wrong.

If `$fDomains` is a string, then the assignment `$fDomains=''` will empty its contents.  If `$fDomains` is an array, it should be initialized as `$fDomains=array()` instead of `$fDomains=""`, and `$fDomains[0]=''` is the correct way to clear the *string value* of the *first element* in the array.

Actually, both of the assignments you illustrated in your comment (as reproduced at the top of this answer) are wrong - there shouldn't be a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the parenthesized expression, and unless you have a string that PHP needs to interpret (e.g., for embedded variables or escape sequences), you should use single quotes instead of double quotes - **`="";`** should be **`=''`**.

Answer (score 1):

According to [bug #71572](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71572) it's not permitted to assign empty string. Then use:

```
substr(fDomains,1); //like Kris Roofe wrote;
```

or use solutions like this:

```
$fDomainsTmp = $fDomains;
for($x = 0 ; $x < length($fDomains); $x ++){
    if(condition character allow in string){ 
      $fDomainsTmp .= $fDomains[$x]; 
    }
}
$fDomains = $fDomainsTmp;
```