# Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset wordPress 4.9.5

Tags: php, wordpress

> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /home/bofi9rpybgx8/public_html/stagging/hello/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 426

Comment: What is in line `426`.

Comment: This is a position of the line

Comment: Yo. You are doing something wrong. I am very delighted when you share this line with me anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092218/cannot-assign-an-empty-string-to-a-string-offset

Answer (score 3):

I notice that problem in somewhere in the net try to replace in line 426

```
        foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !is_scalar($value) )
            continue;

        $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
```

With

```
        foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !is_scalar($value) )
            continue;

        if (!empty($value)) {
            $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this solution you need replace your this code at your line number

From :

```
    foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( ! is_scalar( $value ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        $l10n[ $key ] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );
    }
```

To:

```
foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !is_scalar($value) )
            continue;

        if (!empty($value) && !empty($key) ) {
            $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
    }
```

Because in my site its showing : Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset  Error that's why i am checking offset $key - is it empty or not. and yes its working for me.